# Is there a way to change text during gameplay in Unity as if it were a text box

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, text, game-engine

As asked above, is there a way to change a text element and store it as a variable in Unity during gameplay, which can then be used in code?

I haven't found anywhere that says you can change text by doing something like clicking on it as if it were a text box, so I was wondering if this was possible or and how.

Comment: You can access the text of a label and have a text box users can type in. Its all in the documentation

Comment: @BugFinder Is it possible to elaborate more? I'm not sure I understand, I can't find that game object

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Text Mesh Pro then the variable type is TMP_Text, if not then the variable type is just Text.

e.g.:

```
public class TextSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text textMeshPro;
    [SerializeField] private Text unityDefaultText;

    public void SetText(string text)
    {
        textMeshPro.text = text;
        unityDefaultText.text = text;
    }
}
```

Side note: if you're using Unity's default text (not the Text Mesh Pro), then switch to Text Mesh Pro, it's a much better package in all terms.

Comment: Ah okay, I get that, I'm still uncertain of how to change text during gameplay from a players perspective

Comment: you would have to be more specific, what do you mean? Can you provide pictures?